# How do you get the XAML designer for XAML Pages in a Shared Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, uwp-xaml, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to get **XAML** pages built inside a shared project to be edited in the **XAML** designer.  If I open a **XAML** page inside of a **WPF** project it works.  This is very frustrating.  Looks like I'll have to design in a **WPF** project and then move the pages to the shared project afterward, unless, of course, there's a way to make the **XAML** designer work with Shared Projects.

Comment: Does it really have to be a shared project or would a project that is shared by different solutions work?

Comment: Can netstandard2.1 handle a XAML library without to specify either .Net Framework or UWP?  I'm doing some research on different XAML based UI for Windows and was hoping to reuse the same XAML files so that my tests wouldn't have any chance of being incorrect because they aren't the same.

Comment: Wpf and uwp xaml is similar but different. Why is uwp even on your  list if candidate techs?

Comment: Because UWP is wayyyy faster than WPF, it's completely sandboxed, it deploys it's entire dependency stack with the app, Windows Store makes the entire commerce area of Windows bog simple, plus you get free update pushes to your customers.